# How to add status information to a list of words in wordpress

Tags: plugins

all I need help in understanding how to add status to the list of words as shown in the link https://paste.pics/BWWDI as I need to know would I show as hot, new, popular, etc.

The required line I have marked with yellow color.
Awaiting for earliest reply

Comment: Where does the list of words come from? If it’s from a theme or plugin then that would be off topic, so you would need to ask the author.

Comment: Hi it's not default from theme or plugin, I have just added the list of data manually as a table in WordPress